# evalInSandbox fails to find function in Firefox 38

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I use Components.utils.evalInSandbox to execute js function in my firefox extension. But this api fails after I upgrade firefox to version 38.

it always throws error "*** js function not defined", which seems that there is no such js function on web page. However, the reality is the js function is just on the web page. I can execute it from web console.

I didn't find this api obsolete in MDN, so what's wrong with this api?

```
var s = Components.utils.Sandbox(document.defaultView.wrappedJSObject);
s.window = document.defaultView.wrappedJSObject;
s.document = document;
s.jsFunctionResult = null;
var javascript = "jsFunctionResult = JSFunctionName(arg1, arg2);";
Components.utils.evalInSandbox("with(window){" + javascript + "}", s);
```

I try to execute alert, it also says "alert is undefined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read this correctly you are creating a Sandbox with the same security principal as the document but with an empty global scope, therefore `JSFunctionName()` will not be available in the global scope of the sandbox.

I guess `with()` should solve that but maybe it does not work across compartment boundaries. Try calling it as `window.wrappedJSObject.JSFunctionName()` instead.